# Items report duplicate

Tags: mysql

I wanted to get a report about the items sold and delivered from particular store,
where in I group them using the item id and store id of course. When I executed to get the delivered stocks. I get the result I wanted but. When I `left join` the sales table, the result of my delivered stocks duplicates. Check below query. As you can read my query you can get my table what it looks like

First I get my stores items, and then `join` to item table to get the ITEM NAME,
then `join` to store table to get the STORE NAME, and then `left join` to delivery table to get the deliveries done to the specific store id, and `left join` again to delivery_items in order to get what are the items with that specific delivery_id has been delivered to that store_id. And so on

```
SELECT s.`store_id`,s.`name` AS `store`,i.`item_id` AS `id`,i.`item_name` AS `fruit`,
sti.`qty` AS `current_stock`, IF(SUM(di.`qty`) IS NULL,0,SUM(di.`qty`)) AS `delivered_stock`
FROM `store_item` sti
LEFT JOIN `item` i
ON i.`item_id` = sti.`item_id`
JOIN `Store` s
ON s.`store_id` = sti.`store_id`
LEFT JOIN `delivery` d
ON d.`store_id` = s.`store_id`
LEFT JOIN `delivery_item` di
ON di.`delivery_id` = d.`delivery_id`
AND di.`item_id` = i.`item_id`
GROUP BY i.`item_id`,s.`store_id`
ORDER BY s.`store_id`,i.`item_id` ASC
```

This is the first query which is working as spected
[image]

But once I added the sales table to get the sold stocks. Everything duplicates. My head is aching already. I've been solving this all day long trying to add more in `group` clause but I can't get my expected result.

This is the query with added sales table

```
SELECT s.`store_id`,s.`name` AS `store`,i.`item_id` AS `id`,i.`item_name` AS `fruit`,
sti.`qty` AS `current_stock`, IF(SUM(di.`qty`) IS NULL,0,SUM(di.`qty`)) AS `delivered_stock`
,IF(SUM(sli.`qty`) IS NULL,0,SUM(sli.`qty`)) AS `sold_stock`
FROM `store_item` sti
LEFT JOIN `item` i
ON i.`item_id` = sti.`item_id`
JOIN `Store` s
ON s.`store_id` = sti.`store_id`
LEFT JOIN `delivery` d
ON d.`store_id` = s.`store_id`
LEFT JOIN `delivery_item` di
ON di.`delivery_id` = d.`delivery_id`
AND di.`item_id` = i.`item_id`
LEFT JOIN `sale` sl
ON sl.`store_id` = s.`store_id`
LEFT JOIN `sale_item` sli
ON sli.`item_id` = i.`item_id`
AND sli.`sale_id` = sl.`sale_id`
GROUP BY i.`item_id`,s.`store_id`
ORDER BY s.`store_id`,i.`item_id` ASC
```

And I got a result with duplicates
[image]

Comment: Read this: [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already made some tricks to get what i need,

I just used UNION in order to get the desired results

```
SELECT MAX(currentStock) AS currentStock,MAX(delivered) AS delivered
FROM (
SELECT SUM(current_stock) AS currentStock,NULL AS delivered
FROM ...

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL AS currentStock,SUM(delivered) AS delivered
FROM ...
) as temp
```